JWT Authentication Issue: Postman Works, Axios Fails in VueJS Project
I have a bit of trouble with authentication-request in my VueJS project using Axios.


What works
When I send a POST request to https://xyz.blabla/api/authenticate using Postman with the following body:
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "rememberMe": true
}

I get the token back as a response :as expected: (see Postman screenshot).
Trouble
But when I send the same request using Axios, I don't get the token! (see error screenshot). Here's my code:
<script lang="ts" setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import { type Ref, ref } from 'vue';

const authenticationError: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
const login: Ref<string> = ref('');
const password: Ref<string> = ref('');
const rememberMe: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);

const doLogin = async () => {
// LOOK HERE
  const data = { username: login.value, password: password.value, rememberMe: rememberMe.value };
  console.log(data);

  try {
// AND LOOK HERE
    const result = await axios.post('https://xyz.blabla/api/authenticate', data);
    const bearerToken = result.headers.authorization;
    console.info('bearerToken: ', bearerToken);
    if (bearerToken && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
      const jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
      if (rememberMe.value) {
        localStorage.setItem('jhi-authenticationToken', jwt);
        sessionStorage.removeItem('jhi-authenticationToken');
      } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem('jhi-authenticationToken', jwt);
        localStorage.removeItem('jhi-authenticationToken');
      }
      console.log('jwt Token: ', jwt);
    }
    authenticationError.value = false;
  } catch (_error) {
    console.error('Login failed! ERROR: ', _error);
    authenticationError.value = true;
  }
};
</script>
<template>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <v-alert v-if="authenticationError"><strong>Login failed!</strong>
      Please check your credentials and try again.
    </v-alert>
  </div>
  <v-sheet class="mx-auto" width="300">
    <v-form fast-fail @submit.prevent>
      <v-text-field v-model="login" type="text" autofocus label="Username"></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field v-model="password" type="password" autofocus label="Password"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn class="mt-2" type="submit" @click="doLogin" block>Submit</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<route lang="yaml">
meta:
  layout: home
</route>

My guess
Anyone have an idea why I'm getting the token with Postman but not with Axios? I'm thinking it might have something to do with headers, CORS, or the request configuration, but I'm not really sure. Any help or tips would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :pray:
I tried in Postman and it works fine as mentioned and as you can see in Screenshot.

Thanks for response.
I'm a beginner, so please tell why does request per Postman work. Is there a different API involved then?

The accepted answer on the duplicate question specifically mentions Postman to address that point.

I'll look into it. Thank you.

Found Solution:
So, as Quentin pointed out, it was definitely a CORS issue.
Heres the thread he mentioned Same Origin Policy.
Basically, Postman ignores CORS completely since it's just a regular desktop app, but when I was using my browser at localhost:3000, it counted as a different domain using Browser API, which triggered CORS restrictions on the server.
To fix this, I added a proxy in my vite.config.mts, since I'm using Vite in my Vue Project, to forward the requests to the API.
All requests to api goes threw the created proxy, which acts as it its origin is from the
Here's what it looks like:
server: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://xyz.blabla/',
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
},

Now, in my Axios call, I just use '/api/authenticate' instead of the full URL:
const result = await axios.post('/api/authenticate', data, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

... and boom, the request goes through the proxy. 
Hope this helps someone else too!
